# C# Why switch to alert not detected in Chrome selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication, proxy, alert

I know that this question asked tens of times but still no answer working.

I’m using Selenium 4 with Chrome 99 and here’s the code:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
string StrProxy = "ip:port";
Proxy p = new Proxy();

p.HttpProxy = StrProxy;
p.SslProxy = StrProxy;
p.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
options.Proxy = p;

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://myip.com");
//driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://username:password@myip.com"); not working


WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();

/* get an error:
OpenQA.Selenium.NoAlertPresentException: 'no such alert 
(Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.51)'*/

alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("username", "password");
alert.Accept();
```

Comment: Do you see the alert popping up?

Comment: If you are setting the proxy, is the proxy performing authentication for you? If it is, then there might not be an alert requesting you to enter a username and password -- hence the NoSuchAlertException.

Comment: Thanks @Greg Burghardt, yes, authentication popup appears

Comment: I don't think the authentication pop up is an alert. I don't believe Selenium allows you to interact with the authentication pop up, now that I think about it.

Comment: yes it looks like that, I'm afraid that there's no solution

https://prnt.sc/VcGyincdDX2G

Answer (score 0):

1. Try a higher wait time value:

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   ```
2. Make sure that manually - an alert is actually showing up. Don't just switch to the alert, accept it:

   ```
   driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
   ```

Comment: Thanks Tal, I already tried but it’s the same, as I noticed from other articles that the reason is the popup is a confirm, not an alert window, Selenium defines it as an alert if it contains one button only.